# Renaming PyCharm project does not change name at top of window

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I can refactor the project by right clicking on it in the menu on the left. However, this does not change the name in the blue bar right at the top of the PyCharm window, where it also shows the project path on your machine. Why not?

Answer (score 23):

The UI doesn't seem to set the configuration files correctly.  It is probably a bug.

If you edit: `<projectdir>/.idea/.name` you can set the name there.

You will have to restart PyCharm for this to take effect.

Comment: I was also needed to rename the <projectName>.iml file

Answer (score 14):

Today I have reached the same problem.
I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895823/6705161), but I have not found this `<projectdir>/.idea/.name`.

So I renamed the `<projectdir>/.idea/<projectName>.iml`, but I realized that this is not enough.

For fully working solution I had to:

1. Change name of projectdir
2. Rename the `<projectdir>/.idea/<projectName>.iml` file
3. Rebuild virtualenv (because I used it on this module)
4. Change all paths to file `<projectName>.iml` and virtualenv directory (in my case: )  inside each xml file on folder `.idea` (In my case was files name: `modules.xml` and `workspace.xml` -> that is mine home directory for all projects)
5. Change name of module (projectName) inside xml file (in my case: `workspace.xml`) on each that line contain:

   - `<favorites_list name="<projectName>" />`
   - `<option name="myItemId" value="<projectName>" />`
   - `<module name="<projectName>" />`
   - `<ignored path="<projectName>.iws" />` -> *but I am not 100% sure about this one.*
6. And finally restart pyCharm and set current virtualenv as Python Interpretor

For Info: I am working on pyCharm Community Edition 2016.2 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

If someone knows easier way, please feel free to inform me.

Answer (score 3):

I came also across this problem and the solution is much much much much (and many more 'much' ) simpler.

The menu at the top right is a menu of the run configurations. Upon renaming the file and if the file has been run/debuged previously, there is a case where the run configuration is not updated.

To correct this, expand the menu just at the left of the 'Play' button at the top right and select 'Edit Configurations'.

From there, find the configuration that you want by selecting it from the menu at the left. At the right pane, at the top, there is the field 'Name'. You can change the content of that field to the new name of the script and you are done.

For example:

Lets say that I have the script foo.py and I rename it to bar.py. At the top right of the PyCharm, there is the 'foo' at the immediate left of the 'Play' button.

I expand the menu at the immediate left of the play button and I choose the 'Edit configurations' choice. Then, I choose foo from the left pane. At the right pane, at the top, and in the field 'Name' I enter 'bar'.

Now, when I want to run the bar.py, the configuration bar will be run.

Comment: But you are talking about changing **script - file** name, and the problem is about **Project - main/root folder** name

Answer (score 3):

In the `Project Tool Window` (`Alt + 1`) right click on the project folder `-> Refactor -> Rename` (`Shift + F6`). A short menu pops up, where you can choose between `Rename directory` and `Rename project`. They are working independently: the first only changes the directory name, and leaves the old project name, the latter only changes the project name, and leaves the directory name the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by doing:

1. Edit the name of `<projectdir>/.idea/<projectName>.lml` to match the project name
2. Change the name of .lml file in the `<projectdir>/.idea/modules.xml` file.
3. Restart PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

You can also check **pycache** folder. You can delete it, if it is there, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I took, if helpful to someone:

1. Change the name of your project folder.
2. Rename your virtual environment to the new name. (I simply made a copy of my conda env and deleted the old one)
3. Delete the `./.idea` folder.
4. Shut down PyCharm.
5. Open your project folder as a new PyCharm project.